# How store a value in a regex to use in the same regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

i have the following regular expression:

```
(.*?MINISTÉRIO\sDO\sTRABALHO\sE\sEMPREGO.*?PÁG\s:\s\d+/(\d+\b)   HOW ACCESS HERE?  )
```

I would like to know, how can i access the value of (\d+\b) in the same regular expression.. I don't want actually match the (\d+\b), but i want save it for use in the next steps.. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you ask about how to get the text matched with a capture group: use `match2 = reg.exec(string)[1];`. Or, if there will be just one match: `match2 = string.match(reg)[1]`. Certainly, error checks must be added.

Comment: not really.. i want access the dinamically value (\d+\b) in the same regex, if is not possible, than i need two regular expressions..

Comment: Do you mean a backreference `\1`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sS4yK0/1).

Comment: HM.. yes, that what i was looking for.. I have this GIANT string with several documents inside.. and each document starts with 0001/SOME NUMBER and ends with SOME NUMBER/ SOME NUMBER.. something like that: http://www.regexr.com/3c66i .. in this example i just copy and past the same document.. 0001/0026. So, i need split this strings, do you know if with this regex i can push to a match variable using a while loop?? @stribizhev

Comment: @stribizhev http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meQvzM?editors=001 like that, but without pushing the 0026, i just want the text, really..

Comment: thanks for your help.. i'm trying here too...

Comment: Please check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYQwem?editors=001). I made some enhancements as in the previous answer to your question, added `/g` global flag to the regex, and replaced `re.exec` with `string.match` since you only need whole matched texts, no submatches required. Right?

Comment: YES!!!!!!!.. OH MY GOD.. are you the god of regex? WTF? :O!!! Thank you very much @stribizhev.. post as an answer, please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You csan use

```
/MINISTÉRIO\sDO\sTRABALHO\sE\sEMPREGO(?:[^P]*(?:P(?!ÁG\s:\s\d+\/\d+)[^P]*)*)PÁG\s:\s\d+\/(\d+)\b(?:\D*(?:(?!\1\/\1)\d\D*)*)\1\/\1(?:[^Z]*(?:Z(?!6:\s\d+)[^Z]*)*)Z6:\s\d+/g
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/gG3yA5/1) and [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYQwem?editors=001).

I made some enhancements as in the previous answer to your question, added `/g` global flag to the regex, and replaced `re.exec` with `string.match` since you only need whole matched texts, no submatches required.

JS code:

```
var s = 'YOU_STRING';
var reg = /MINISTÉRIO\sDO\sTRABALHO\sE\sEMPREGO(?:[^P]*(?:P(?!ÁG\s:\s\d+\/\d+)[^P]*)*)PÁG\s:\s\d+\/(\d+)\b(?:\D*(?:(?!\1\/\1)\d\D*)*)\1\/\1(?:[^Z]*(?:Z(?!6:\s\d+)[^Z]*)*)Z6:\s\d+/g;
var matches = s.match(reg);
console.log(matches);
```